# Is "activity" the right word to use here?

Tags: word-choice

Is *activity* the right word to use in this sentence, or should I use something else?

> Could you please confirm was there any activity with the client server?
>    In the above sentence , I want to get a confirmation from server team that are they doing any testing(activity) with the client server?

It is to get information about the server unavailability ..  Hope now It's clear

Comment: Better word than what?  *Activity*?

Comment: @snailboat yes. Better word than activity mentioned in the below sentence.

Comment: Even allowing for the missing article (it's **the** server), this doesn't sound at all good to me. I can't tell whether it's supposed to mean *"Was there any **communication** with the server?"*, or *"Was there any activity **on** the server?"*, or something different. But whatever it's supposed to mean, it's not well-expressed.

Comment: We can't really answer your question because we don't know what _activity_ refers to. We can't give you alternatives if we don't know _what_ activity you are talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence should be

"Could you please confirm whether there was any activity with the client server?"

or, less formally,

"Was there any activity with the client server?"